# MSSQL Procedure IF Statement don't work

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a procedure with an easy `IF-ELSE-Statement`. But everytime just jump into the ELSE block. But the IF is true.

I tried three ways

```
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserTable WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password)
IF @Count > 0
BEGIN
    SET @SessionID = CONVERT(varchar(32), NEWID())
    PRINT 'IF Clause'
    SET @Response = @SessionID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ELSE Clause'
    SET @Response = 'error 401'
END
```

and

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserTable WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password) > 1
```

and

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password)
```

I wrote a script to test the procedure, there I check the SELECT-statements, too. They are correct.

Edit:
Do I call my procedure wrongly?

```
EXEC dbo.UPLogin @Username = 'test', @Password = 'test1234', @Response = @Response Output
SELECT @Response
```

best regards

Comment: It's hard to say if you're calling the procedure wrong, because you didn't post the definition of the procedure; you only posted an out-of-context portion of it. Also, did you try `PRINT @Count` after the line where you `SET @Count`?

Comment: Yes you are right, but thanks so I found my error. :)  I declared my parameters wrong. I wrote:

Username nvarchar instead of Username nvarchar(32)

Comment: OK. So either post a self-answer (by editing the one you deleted, perhaps) to provide the solution to others, or delete your question if you no longer need it answered.

Comment: Please consider either un-deleting your answer and accept it or delete the question all together.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found my error.
I declared my parameters wrong.
I wrote:

```
@Username nvarchar
@Password nvarchar
```

instead of:

```
@Username nvarchar(32),
@Password nvarchar(32)
```